# What damage type is a Kobold's explosion?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've built an Apprentice character that only has about 500 HP and Kobolds in the later waves of challenges have started to one shot my character. This makes it fairly difficult to repair towers once I get behind.

So, I'm curious if Kobold explosions are a specific damage type, like fire, so I could build up some resistances against them so they don't destroy my poor towers only Apprentice build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The damage type is fire. I would, however, focus more on building so that they won't ever hit you or your crystal, seeing as they get pretty powerful.

Source for damage type: http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Kobold

Comment: Also bear in mind two things: 1) The game is best played with all slots filled.  If you are trying to solo on the higher levels, kobolds won't be your only problem. 2) In game, even when solo, you can swap characters during build phase.  That means you can build other towers with the other classes.  The squire in particular has better barricades than the wimpy apprentice ones, so those might be a better choice.  (Focusing apprentice towers on DPS instead)